# Рассылка почты из php скрипта через smtp

Tags: php, smtp

Здравствуйте, решил сделать рассылку писем через smtp, используя данный скрипт на php:http://i-leon.ru/smtp-php/

В качестве почтового сервера использовал ssl://smtp.mail.ru:465. Однако на этапе авторизации сервер логин принимает, а на этапе принятия пароля выбрасывает ошибку авторизации, что пароль не был принят как верный. Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с похожей проблемой связки php smtp и почтовика mail.ru на ssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, нашел обходное решение для данного вопроса. Для этого использовал готовую библиотеку PHPMailer. Через почтовик yandex сообщения тут же начали отправляться без проблем. Для отправки через gmail потребовалось в настройках почты открыть доступ к ящику со стороны сторонних приложений (как-то так данный пункт именуется). К mail так и не удалось подключиться. Возможно нужно так же поколдовать над настройками почты.
Ссылка на библиотеку:[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)